# Do fullerenes have a better quantum yield than carbon quantum dot's of similar dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, material-science

As a fullerene and a carbon quantum dot of similar dimensions would have the same surface area but different internal volume, as a Fullerene does not contain carbon within it's interior, but just the spin orbit interaction of it's electron's inside, would this affect the quantum yield of the fullerene compared to a carbon one?

Would any other characteristic change, such as the emission and absorption values of it's electronic states? As a fullerene has an empirical formula of Cn, with n being a positive, even parity value, and it, in theory, non-ending, would there be an point in which adding more carbon's would not yield an discrete, electronic states? I say this as normal, crystalline  semiconductor Quantum dot's have a limit to their size in which they display these properties; would the same apply to Fullerenes, despite their empty volume?